# Why iPhone Dictionary never translate to other languages?

Tags: iphone, language, dictionary

When i read a book and long press a word on iPhone, then choose "look up" from the menu, i get English to English translation, and not English to my language.

I already chose and download my language in Dictionary Settings, and restarted, not working.

I also tried to set my language as the default iPhone language, which still didn't work, it keep translating English into English and not my language.

Also tried to mark other languages to download in the Dictionary settings, but didn't help, English to English only, not other languages.

My friend simply chose her language in Dictionary and she has English to other language.

I have latest iOS with iPhone 12.

Comment: What exactly is your language??

Comment: I speak a few, German and Hebrew. Does it matter? I tried Chinese, Danish, but nothing works.

Comment: Is this happening in the Apple Books app?